# Problem when using single quotes or double quotes in formula in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to put this formula in openpyxl:

```
ws.cell(row=2,column=7).value="=IF(ISBLANK('1'!A2),"",SUMIF('1'!C:C,D18,'1'!L:L))"
```

But it will cut it in half because I have "" in the middle, but I cannot use single quotes ' because I want it to bring the Sumif from another sheet, '1'. So basically if A2 from sheet 1 is blank, I want to bring nothing ("")

Is there another method to write the formula without double quotes or single quotes?
Or something else in excel to bring blank?

Comment: Just delimit the quotes with backslashes.

Comment: Why can't you use single quotes? If you're quoting the sheet names, that shouldn't be a problem.